# Design pattern for reporting/monitoring progress of long processes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reporting, progress

Anyone can suggest a good Design Pattern for reporting/monitoring status/progress of long processes.
Basically, I have a codebase that receives a "data-context" object:

```
public class DataContext : IDataContext
{
    pulbic Dictionary<string, objects> Properties { get; private set; }

    // Additional properties removed for simplicity...
}
```

Based on the provided context, a Task (not TPL-Task) object is created, with various subtasks.
During execution, the DataContext object is passed to the various sub-tasks, which can retrieve or update it.

For example, let's say that the main task is a "Copy files" task. The DataContext will have properties like the SourceFolder and TargetFolder, and perhaps a FilterFiles property (e.g. *.docx). Our main task will be a CopyFilesTasks, and it will have a "pipeline" of subtasks - Scan Folders, Scan Files, Filter Files, Copy Files, etc....

What I am looking for, is the best way to allow the task/sub-tasks to report their progress to the caller/executer. 
In our example above, the changes in progress might be just "Copied file ABC.docx...", or perhaps something a bit more "complex", like "Scanning folder XYZ..."

I have considered the following options:

1. **INotifyPropertyChanged**: add a "Progress" property to DataContext

   public string Progress { get; set { _progress = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Progress"); }

   and have the code that created the DataContext object register to the PropertyChanged event. However, this seems like a too-simplistic approach...
2. **ILog** (using whatever logging framework you prefer): use an ILog instance in the various tasks/sub-tasks, and have the main-task executioner add it's own listener to the logging framework.
   However this seemed like bending the logging mechanism to do things it was not supposed to do.
3. **Udi Dahan's [DomainEvents](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)**: The executioner of the task can regard the DataContext as a "domain", and therefore we can try to implement an "EventHandler" for a "ProgressChanged" event. In theory, this can be even used for more refined events, that happen in specific sub-tasks... But once again, it feels like forcing the concept...

My concerns include things like:

- Progress might not be the only "event" that needs to be monitored - in our example above, we might want things more defined, like FolderHandled, FileCopied, etc., but we might not know the exact events when executing the tasks (remember - the subtasks are created based on the DataContext, and might result in different tasks being executed).
- The context of running the tasks is not yet defined. For now, I'm just planning to run the tasks from the command-line application, so outputting to the command-line is needed for debugging. Later on, when I move this to a service, I might want to have a "listener" update a database with the task's progress (for example).

Answer (score 2):

You can declare arguments for each possible operation type, say FileOperationEventArgs for file operation, DatabaseUpdateEventArgs for database operation etc.

```
public class FileOperationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly string SourceFolder;
    public readonly string TargetFolder;

    public FileOperationEventArgs(string sourceFolder, string targetFolder)
    {
        SourceFolder = sourceFolder;
        TargetFolder = targetFolder;
    }
}

public class DatabaseUpdateEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly int RowsUpdated;

    public DatabaseUpdateEventArgs(int rowsUpdated)
    {
        RowsUpdated = rowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

OperationProgress class declares events for each operation type.

```
public class OperationProgress
{
    public event EventHandler<FileOperationEventArgs> FileCopied;
    public event EventHandler<DatabaseUpdateEventArgs> DatabaseUpdated;

    public void OnFileCopied(FileOperationEventArgs a)
    {
        if(FileCopied != null)
            FileCopied(this, a);
    }

    public void OnDatabaseUpdated(DatabaseUpdateEventArgs a)
    {
        if (DatabaseUpdated != null)
            DatabaseUpdated(this, a);
    }
}
```

OperationProgress will be specified when DataContext is created.

```
public class DataContext : IDataContext
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; private set; }
    public OperationProgress Progress { get; private set; }

    public DataContext(OperationProgress progress)
    {
        Progress = progress;
    }
}
```

Subtask implementation can update the progress.

```
public class FileCopySubTask
{
    public void Execute(DataContext context)
    {
        context.Progress.OnFileCopied(new FileOperationEventArgs("c:/temp1", "c:/temp2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to Udi Dahan's DomainEvents, but more restricted - it limits the events only for specific "known" events - I'll have to compile everything in case of new tasks with new events... it also means that I'll have to manage events registration/unregistration and references if I have multiple tasks and multiple "listeners"...

Answer (score -2):

Consider BackgroundWorkers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx
They have their own reportprogress event on a separate UI thread.

Comment: This is not what I need - I have no problem running the code in background threads... I'm looking for a more "complete" solution, and not just how to update a progress-bar in the UI (BTW, I don't even have a UI at the moment, and will probably never will)